# Landscape update package stuck at "in progress"

Tags: 16.04, landscape

I'm trying to get Landscape to upgrade my packages but it is stuck at "in progress". This is true when I try to update even a single item. I do have the latest landscape service installed on the server. Any suggestions.

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: is Patience an option?  Because when you update *everything* it can take a while for those upgrades to actually complete, especially when Kernels are installed.

Comment: When I only select 1 item, it shouldn't take long. We are not talking everything, only 1 item on the list.

Comment: I started the upgrade for "Upgrade package cloud-init 19.1-1-gbaa47854-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 to 19.2-24-ge7881d5c-0ubuntu1~16.04.1" on Tuesday 9/17 at 7:32am. As of Friday 9/20 9:24am it still has not finished.

Comment: After 21 days, still no help and still having the same issue. Nor can I get help at Canonical. At this point, my opinion of Landscape is that it is worthless, at least for me.

Comment: Same here. I ended up cancelling and installing manually, but why? I mean, is this how is supposed to work?